# Passing gstring to javascript function in Grails

Tags: javascript, grails

I am passing a gstring as a parameter to a javascript function as shown:

```
<div class="btn btn-small" id="helpful" onClick="helpful(${value})">Helpful</div>
```

Here, value comes from controller which is dynamic. I have javascript function as:

```
function helpful(answer){
        $.post("${createLink(controller: "reviews", action: "dataFromReviews")}",
                {
                    helpful:true,
                    answer:answer
                }
        );
    }
```

But I am not getting any response. No error while inspecting. Can't we pass gstring in javascript? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the generated HTML look like? I would think that you have a javascript error in it because you are not quoting the extrapolated string you are using as a parameter for the 'helpful' function. This should work:

```
<div class="btn btn-small" id="helpful" onClick="helpful('${value}')">Helpful</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou very much @helgew. This was a silly mistake. I feel embarrassed to have asked it

Answer (score 1):

As @helgew suggests, check the output. Also note that grails >2.3 will HTML encode anything passed in with a GString unless you have disabled this (grails.views.default.code='none'). You'll need to use the raw codec to avoid the encoding. Use with caution:

```
<div class="btn btn-small" id="helpful" onClick="helpful('${raw(value)}')">Helpful</div>
```